# OpenLayer Map restrict panning and zooming

Tags: zooming, openlayers

I am new to OpenLayers, and am trying to figure out how to restrict the amount that a user can pan around and zoom outward. For this application, the user chooses a local area in the map and clicks a button saying to use that area, and we want them not to be able to pan outside of or zoom out greater than that extent. When the button is clicked, I am setting both the maxRestrictedExtent and the maxExtent to the current extent using map.GetExtent().  I am also setting the maxResolution to the current resolution by calling map.getResolution(). Panning works perfectly, but zooming doesn't.  The user is still able to zoom out passed the given resolution.

I have added code which, every time the extent changes, prints out the current extent and resolution.  On the 6th extent change I set the three map properties listed above and print out the settings.  This allows me to zoom in from full world view to a localized enough area for testing.  On the 6th extent change, I zoom out with my mouse wheel and see the extent and resolution that were chosen.  On zooming out with one click of my mouse wheel, the next printout shows clearly that the resolution is indeed larger than the setting for map.maxResolution, and I can see that the viewable area is larger than the one chosen.  I have tried a number of things, including setting maxExtent, but nothing seems to cause the max zoomable extent to be restricted.  I can zoom all the way out to full world view again if I like.

Below you can see the test code that I have written which instantiates a map with a Navigation control and an OSM layer, and then registers for the map's moveend event, creating a callback function that does what I have described, and finally zooms to max extent.

Does anyone have an idea as to what I should be doing differently in order to limit the ability to zoom out to the max extent chosen?  I am hoping that I will not have to manually adjust the extent back to within the max extent, but if that's the case, at least knowing that would help.

P.S. - Unfortunately the whole html doesn't show, since from  to just before style, and from after the final  are being processed as html.  The only thing that is really missing is that I call init() in the onload event of the body.

```
<style type="text/css">    
    html, body {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;         
    }
    #map {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;         
    } 
</style>

<script src="http://www.openlayers.org/api/OpenLayers.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

var map;
var num;

function init(){
    map = new OpenLayers.Map('map', { controls: [] });       
    map.addControl(new OpenLayers.Control.Navigation());       
    map.addLayer(new OpenLayers.Layer.OSM());

    map.events.register("moveend", this, function (e) {
        if (num == 5)
        {
            map.maxExtent = map.getExtent();
            map.restrictedExtent = map.maxExtent;
            map.maxResolution = map.getResolution();
            console.log(num++ + ": Setting maxExtent/restrictedExtent: " + map.maxExtent + "; resolution: " + map.maxResolution);
        }
        else
        {
            console.log(num++ + ": Changed to extent: " + map.getExtent() + "; resolution: " + map.getResolution());
        }
    });

    num = 0;
    map.zoomToMaxExtent();
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've just done exactly what you want to do, and it's working for me.

When I create the map, I'm specifying the min/max resolutions

```
  map = new OpenLayers.Map('map_element', {
    minResolution: 0.02197265625,
    maxResolution: 0.00274658203125
});
```

When adding a layer, I also specify a list of serverResolutions.

```
    var tilecache_disk_layer = new OpenLayers.Layer.TileCache("TileCache Layer",
        ["http://" + tilecache_host + "/tilecache/"],
        "basic",
        {
         serverResolutions: [0.703125, 0.3515625, 0.17578125, 0.087890625, 
                        0.0439453125, 0.02197265625, 0.010986328125, 
                        0.0054931640625, 0.00274658203125, 0.001373291015625, 
                        0.0006866455078125, 0.00034332275390625, 0.000171661376953125, 
                        0.0000858306884765625, 0.00004291534423828125, 0.000021457672119140625]
        },
        {wrapDateLine: 'true'},
        {isBaseLayer: true}
    );
```

The following javascript sends a request off to my server to get the map parameters.

```
  if (site_coords == undefined) {
    coordinates = sendHttpRequest("http://" + tile_host + "/ManagerApp/mapView?position=true");
    mapParameters = coordinates.split(",");       
    map.setCenter(new OpenLayers.LonLat(mapParameters[0], mapParameters[1]));
    map.minResolution = mapParameters[2];
    map.maxResolution = mapParameters[3];
    zoom_level = mapParameters[4];
    map.restrictedExtent = new OpenLayers.Bounds(mapParameters[5], mapParameters[6], mapParameters[7], mapParameters[8])
}
```

Comment: I can see there's a lot to learn.  New to geo as well.  From your min/max resolutions, I can see that you set your min to be a larger number than your max. This is a little confusing since when I first bring up my page with the console running, I get a resolution of 19567.87923828125, and when I finally get to my sixth extent change, I'm around about 4.x or so. The map seems to be telling me that the closer I get in is the lower the resolution.

Comment: Just talked a geo colleague who says that resolution is usually measured as meters per pixel, which would mean that when I'm very close in, I have less meters shown in one pixel as a small number, even less than 1, and very far out I'll have a greater number of meters shown in one pixel as a large number, which is what I'm seeing.  So I'm not understanding why minResolution would be set to a larger number than maxResolution.

Comment: Resolution is the width/height in map units per pixel—so, for example, 150 miles divided
by 512 pixels would be a resolution of 0.29296875. If you are using a tile cache server,
you will need to specify the resolutions at which the tiles are cached (as well as set the
serverResolutions property, which specifies the resolutions at which the tiles are cached
on the server). Otherwise, you will often simply just define the numZoomLevels to specify
how many zoom levels you want.

Comment: If you define numZoomLevels, but don't have a tile cache server (not sure if we do I'll have to check), would you then leave out the resolutions array and leave it up to the map to figure that out?  And then, if there are, say 20 zoom levels, my next question would be how I would know which zoom level to set my max at when a user chooses an area for their extent?

Comment: Well I initially tried setting numZoomLevels, but for some reason had problems with that approach, so I switched to using resolutions. I also notice that you're using a completely different layer type to me (OSM). Your problem with using a TileCache layer is that it's your responsibility to populate the map tiles. Which is where I am at the moment - getting hold of the data to pre-populate the cache.

Comment: So I updated my file, adding a minResolution and maxResolution setting in the construction of the OpenLayers.Map object, and adding a serverResolutions array option to the construction of the OSM layer.  Looked it up and this is supported.  Got my resolutions from this link (http://simonmercier.net/blog/?p=88).  Then, again in my event, on the sixth call, I set maxRestrictedExtent and the maxResolution.  But even though I can see that these calls are set, and that the resolution is in my array, I can still zoom out passed the chosen resolution.  Something's still missing.

Answer (score 0):

So here's my answer.  After much searching, posting and emailing, I found someone who told me a simple answer.  I was already registering for the "moveend" event, capturing all extent movements, so that I could take a look at what was going on.  The answer was to just declare an private int variable (maxZoomLevel) on the class, which has a value of zero when the map is first drawn, since I'm drawing world view to start, and then is set to the current zoom level with getZoom() at the time the user clicks on the button, choosing the current area to work with.  So then the registration for the "moveend" event looks like this:

```
    map.events.register("moveend", this, function (e) {
        if (map.getZoom() < maxZoomLevel)
        {
            map.zoomTo(maxZoomLevel);
        }
    });
```

Since world view is 0, and ground-most view is 19, then if the current view is less than the max (the chosen zoom level), we just zoom to the max.

This works great.  I does flicker a bit while I'm scrolling the mouse to zoom out passed the max chosen zoom level, but it no longer zooms out passed it.  Also, this method did not require me to add a resolution array to my map layer, or to set a max/min resolution on the map.  (Wish I could get rid of that flicker...  Hmmm!)